# Trigonometry in libGDX - velocity and angle

Tags: libgdx

For my game i wanted to use trigonometry. As i have initialy searched everything was the same as it was in Actionscript3. But i was wrong. Nothing worked as it should. So after searching the libGDX forum and stachoverflow posts i have "played" with numbers and find solution. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

How to calculate an angle in libgdx and how to set x and y velocity with trigonometry (code omitted for clarity):

```
//variables
private Object object;
private float touchX, touchY, angle, xSpeed, ySpeed;
private final int power = 5;

//touch up event
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    touchX = screenX;
    touchY = h - screenY; // screenX gives an inverted y position (y == 0 is at the top)
    setPosition(touchX, touchY);        
}

//set angle and velocity method
public void setPosition(int x, int y){
    //example 1 (velocity is calculated without angle):
    angle = (float) (Math.atan2(y - object.y, x - object.x) * tdg) - 90.0f;
    //at the end there is not always -90.0f. It depends of how the texture (or sth else we 
    //want to rotate) is rotated in .png file. Play with nuber if -90.0f is not good. Use 
    //the scale from -360 to 360
    xSpeed = (x - bx) / 30;
    ySpeed = (y - by) / 30;

    //example 2 (velocity with angle):
    angle = (float) Math.atan2(y - object.y, x - object.x);
    xSpeed = (float) (Math.cos(angle)*power);
    ySpeed = (float) (Math.sin(angle)*power);
    angle = (angle*180/Math.PI) - 90.0f;
}
```